# Problem in chatbox made in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have made a chatbox in jquery and i want to add the functionality to see "xyz is typing"
for this i have written this code

```
setInterval("typing()", 1000);    
function typing()
{

      var name1= $("#name").val();
      var n=$('#message').val().length();
      if(n>1)
      $('#shout').prepend(name1+'is typing');
}
```

But its not working. Someoen pls help...

Comment: `setInterval(typing, 1000)` is a better solution if you need to use an interval.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `"typing()"`. This will invoke `eval()` internally. Instead, just use `typing`.

If you have made a chatbox, you probably want to send to the server via AJAX that the person has typed something.

Comment: Actually its a shoutbox and its working fine. Here the url http://algoritmus.in/projects/shoutbox/ . Replaced "Typing()" with typing() bt no use

Comment: @Kunal Yeah whoops, don't put the parans at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

lenght() in not a string function is javascript. You can find length of string by using just string.length. Also change prepend() method to html() method otherwise it will repeat same message [xxx is typing] after each interval.

Here is the updated code

```
setInterval("typing()", 1000);
function typing()
{
   var name1= $("#name").val();
   var n=$('#message').val().length;
   if(n>1)
     $('#shout').html(name1+' is typing');
}
```